# How to calculate the average of the first rows of each hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table with values, every five minutes a new row appears in the table with a numerical value and time, how to calculate the average value for the first 45 minutes of each hour.

I have a query that calculates the average value for each hour

```
SELECT hh=CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126),
[Fe_Ka]=AVG([Fe_ka]) FROM Results1 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126) 
ORDER BY hh;
```

but I have no idea how to make a selection of 45 minutes at the beginning of each hour

[Initial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/req0t.png)

[Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7nxs.png)

The initial table includes three columns: Measurement date(datetime), measurement id(int), value(float). A new line is added every five minutes. Need a table with the time by hour and the average value for the first 45 minutes of this hour

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, and expected results in a consumable format please? That'll greatly help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu I provided screenshots

Comment: no screenshot please. Post as text

Comment: `WHERE DATEPART(minute, DateMeasure) BETWEEN 0 AND 44` maybe? Also best way to truncate to the hour is `DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, '20000101', DateMeasure), DateMeasure)`

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data. Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: … See the [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help) for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: @Squirrel i do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEPART()` to get the minute and `CASE` expression and to check for the time is within HH:45 mintues

```
select  TheDate = convert(date, DateMeasure), 
        TheHour = datepart(hour, DateMeasure),
        TheAvg  = avg(case when datepart(minute, DateMeasure) <= 45 then TheVal end)
from    TheTable
group by convert(date, DateMeasure), datepart(hour, DateMeasure)
```